# C++ error: ‘bool operator()(std::pair<Nodo&, float>, std::pair<Nodo&, float>)’ must be a nonstatic member function

Tags: c++, compilador, float, sobrecarga-de-operadores, lenguaje-compilado

Estoy usando una cola de prioridad  formada por un pair de un objeto de una clase llamada `Nodo`y un valor de tipo `float`(lo elegí en lugar de double, pensando que ocupa menos bytes).

El error que me sale es en el operador de comparación `>` que sobrecargué porque la cola de prioridad que uso los valores situados más arriba en la cola son los más pequeños,sin embargo, soy un principiante en C++, y a pesar de revisar el código una y otra vez, no he sido capaz de depurar los errores. Códigos(declaración y definición, en la clase `Nodo`):

```
 friend bool operator()(const pair<Nodo&,float> nodo1,const pair<Nodo&,float> nodo2);

 bool car::operator()(const pair<Nodo& a,float cost1> nodo1,const pair<Nodo& b,float cost2> nodo2){

        return (nodo1.second) > (nodo2.second)

 }
```

errores:

```
error: ‘bool operator()(std::pair<Nodo&, float>, std::pair<Nodo&, float>)’ must be a nonstatic member function
         friend bool operator()(const pair<Nodo&,float> nodo1,const pair<Nodo&,float> nodo2);
                                                                                           ^
car.cpp:68:56: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
     bool car::operator()(const pair<Nodo& a,float cost1> nodo1,const pair<Nodo& b,float cost2> nodo2){
```

Os agradecería también que me dierais consejos prácticos en depuración de código. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es facil. Una función `friend` **no puede** ser una función miembro... por eso precisamente la declaras `friend`, para que pueda acceder a las variables privadas de la clase sin ser miembro de la misma:

```
struct Test1
{
  Test1 operator+(Test1 const&) const
  {
      std:: cout << "Funcion miembro\n";
      return *this;
  }
};

struct Test2
{
  friend Test2 operator+(Test2 const&, Test2 const&);
};

Test2 operator+(Test2 const&, Test2 const&)
{
    std:: cout << "Funcion friend\n";
    return Test2();
}

int main()
{
    Test1 t1;
    t1+t1;

    Test2 t2;
    t2 + t2;;
}
```

No te he puesto el ejemplo con el operador función porque este operador **únicamente** puede ser función miembro:

```
class car
{
public:

    bool operator(pair<Nodo&,float> const& nodo1,pair<Nodo&,float> const& nodo2);
};

bool car::operator()(pair<Nodo&,float> const& nodo1,pair<Nodo&,float> const& nodo2)
{
  // ...
}
```